# Version control for python virtual environments

Tags: python, version-control, virtualenv, python-venv

I am looking for a way to track changes in a virtual environment, namely what packages are installed and their version.

My problem is that (simplified example) if I use `python_package v1.0`, then somehow upgrade to `python_package v2.0` which has breaking changes, my code could stop working, even though I have not changed a single line of it.

If I don't remember that I have upgraded `python_package`, I could be very puzzled by all this.

Now, if I had some version control for my environment, I could first of all know that something has changed, and then just say "revert to this state" and check again my code, to see if with the old versions of my packages my code runs as I expect.

Is there a way to do this? Dumping regularly `requirements.txt` with `pip` and checking for differences with its old version could do it, but it sounds very hacky (and with potential pitfalls).

Comment: [`pip freeze`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/) outputs the installed packages into a requirements.txt form.

Comment: The `requirements.txt` route is fairly standard. That's what you'd use to set the environment up from scratch, so it makes sense to maintain it. Your process just needs to include specifying versions in that file instead of just the package name and making sure you update it. Maybe even update the `requirements.txt` *first* and *then* update the package.

Comment: `requriements.txt` aren't meant to be changed regularly. And it's not hacky it's a very common approach.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych who said they should be changed regularly? This problem can still happen even if you upgrade/add a package rarely

Comment: *Dumping regularly requirements.txt with pip and checking for...*. It can happen, but there is no solution for it unless you check it with a new package manually or with automatic tests.

Comment: Exactly, _dumping_ (not _changing_) regularly. Anyway, I was hoping for a better way than exploting `requirements.txt`, but it seems there is not